# Unable to communicate devices from 2 different L2 switches

Tags: networking, wireless-router, switch

I have Network infra like this:

```
ISP - TPLink AC3150 WiFi Router (port 1) - Cisco SG200         - my devices (TV, PC, Laptop, WebCam, etc.)
                                (port 2) - Cisco Catalyst 2960 - my devices (PC, Laptop, NAS, etc.)
```

My WiFi router has DHCP server 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.199 (MASK 255.255.255.0)

Devices connected to either both SG200 or 2960 are getting DHCP from TPLink AC3150 WiFi Router, and they can get Internet connection as well.

The problem here is: Devices connected to SG200 can't communicate to devices connected in Catalyst 2960 (vice versa)

- I can't ping SG200 to 2960 (vice versa).
- I can't ping Devices connected to SG200 from 2960 (vice versa).
- but I can ping devices in SG200 to another device in SG200.
- and I can ping devices in 2960 to another device in 2960.

Any idea what's possibly went wrong here?

here are my Catalyst2960 config (i'm not sure what is the telnet command to generate this config)

[image]

here are my SG200 config

[image]

*please let me know if you require other config

Comment: Do interfaces of the devices have IP-addresses assigned?

Comment: Yes they do have - means: both from sg200 and catalyst got ip from wifi router dhcp server

Comment: If i take a look in wifi router mgmt console i can see all devices listed in arp list

Comment: Some Wifi routers have a so-called "client isolation" setting. This prevents the connected devices to see each other, even though each device can communicate to the internet. In most Wifi routers this only applies to the Wifi clients, but I have seen some devices that also applied this to the LAN ports. Check the wifi router and switch client isolation off to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: My Wifi router is tplink ac3150 which i believe no client isolation. Actually device within same switch (e.g all device connected to sg200) can communicate each other - the problem is devices connected from sg200 cant communicate with devices connected with catalyst 2690

Comment: Most likely the issue is in the Cisco switches configuration. It might happen that the connection between them does not work as you expect, because they are more sophisticated devices and have more settings than cheaper switches. Are all ports on those switches belong to the same VLAN? (ports that used to connect devices AND ports used for switches interconnection).

Comment: Those switches are in factory default, means, all ports (in both switches) are in vlan 1 (native vlan 1 untagged)

Comment: I see. The most helpful thing you can do is to post output of `show running config` of both switches. Probably someone will be able to recognize a source of the problem.

Comment: Hi @VL-80, i'm not sure if SG200 have CLI and I'm not sure as well command to get config from catalyst2960 - however i have update my question to share my config, let me know if there any specific config that you want to know. i still cant ping device from the other switch (even, i cant ping other device from the other switch from SG200's mgmt console)

Comment: What happens when you connect your Cisco switches to each other? How exactly can’t they communicate? Have you tried Wireshark/tcpdump to diagnose packet flows?

Comment: @DanielB, Initially i did: Router - SG200 (with other devices on the other ports) - 2960 (in SG200 port 2) - another devices ... that can't work as well, device connected to SG 200 can't 'talk' with devices connected with 2960. what i meant by can't communicate is: inaccessible (ping, tracert, etc.)

Comment: Try setting interfaces to General mode and disabling ingress filtering on SG200.

Comment: Thanks @VL-80, just did it to SG200 port1 (connected to Router) and the other ports, still no luck

Comment: Set them all to General or even better to Access mode. Access mode by design makes the port VLAN-unaware. Trunk ports are needed to pass multiple VLANs across switches. Make sure they all have same VLAN id.

Comment: @VL-80, Just change all to access mode (it won't allow me to disable Ingress Filtering - so it is enabled) - and still no luck T_T those switches are in factory default, so they are all on VLAN1 by default. just FYI, my ONT from ISP is carrying 3 VLANs before it goes to router: (10, 20 and 30)  which 10 is the internet line that i use. i'm not sure if that matter.

Comment: I just realized that your switches are plugged in to the router. Did you try to play with router's VLANs settings? Also, try connecting two switches directly and see if devices can talk across the switches in this case. Then you will know for sure if the problem is in the router.

Comment: @VL-80, thanks for your reply, i just tried to remove my Wifi Router like: devices - SG200 - 2960 - devices (without DHCP because not connected to router) and the result is the same, i can't reach the other deviceconnected from diffrent switch (configuration of the SG200 switch are Access mode vlan1 for all ports)